# Azure Webjob is not connecting to the database of the connected website

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

So I have a Azure website. It uses "code-first" entity framework for its database. It works like a champ.

I have a new console application turned webjob that I am connecting to this website and it is supposed to use the same database.

Now everything I have read points me to the direction that the webjob should share the configuration settings of the website which leads me to believe that it should be able to access the database through this sharing of info.

However...when the schedule runs I get the classic

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

error that signifies that my connection string is missing or incorrect.

In my console application for the webjob I have specifically not put in a connection string because, again, I thought they were linked somehow.

My question is simply, what am I misunderstanding here, and/or is there something else I need to do in my console application to get the web job to connect correctly?

**UPDATE**
So I added a traditional connection string into the app and that seems to work just fine. I suppose this is fine, but I was really hoping that I wouldn't have to change my config each time I change environments...thought we were finally passed that.

Thanks!

David

Comment: Did u able to fix this issue? If yes please add it .It ll really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ConfigurationManager to grab your connection string...

e.g., ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_NAME"]